# Adding text to Folium FastMarkerCluster markers?

Tags: python, text, data-visualization, folium

With the following code I attempt to add text to my folium FastMarkerCluster markers.The code below produces a map but with no success for adding the text. The text is contained as a string corresponding to each lon lat pair.

I believe the problem has something to do with the fact that the df containing the text column is a pandas series object. From what I understood this is how it should be specifed in that case 'df.columnname'. However, that didn't work. I also tried turning the column into a list, but with no success with that approach either. Any pointers really appreciated.

```
xlat = guns2013['latitude'].tolist()
xlon = guns2013['longitude'].tolist()
locations = list(zip(xlat, xlon))
map2 = folium.Map(location=[38.9, -77.05], tiles='CartoDB dark_matter', 
zoom_start=1)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(map2)
for point in range(0, len(locations)):
   folium.Marker(locations[point], 
   popup='guns2013.texts'[point]).add_to(marker_cluster)

map2
```

Comment: Note that you are using `MarkerCluster`, not `FastMarkerCluster`. When using `FastMarkerCluster` you can pass a Javascript callback to style the marker (e.g. change the icon), but I am not sure if you can add a popup.
See here: https://medium.com/@bobhaffner/folium-markerclusters-and-fastmarkerclusters-1e03b01cb7b1

Answer (score 10):

I played around with this and ultimately you CAN pass popups from python to the `callback` function like so:

```js
some_map = folium.Map(location=[df['latitude'].mean(), 
   df['longitude'].mean()], 
 zoom_start=9)
               
callback = ('function (row) {' 
                'var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(row[0], row[1]), {color: "red"});'
                'var icon = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({'
                "icon: 'info-sign',"
                "iconColor: 'white',"
                "markerColor: 'green',"
                "prefix: 'glyphicon',"
                "extraClasses: 'fa-rotate-0'"
                    '});'
                'marker.setIcon(icon);'
                "var popup = L.popup({maxWidth: '300'});"
                "const display_text = {text: row[2]};"
                "var mytext = $(`<div id='mytext' class='display_text' style='width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;'> ${display_text.text}</div>`)[0];"
                "popup.setContent(mytext);"
                "marker.bindPopup(popup);"
                'return marker};')
                             
some_map.add_child(FastMarkerCluster(df[['latitude', 'longitude','use_code_name']].values.tolist(), callback=callback))
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to add multiple texts to the pop up? i.e. `df[['latitude', 'longitude','use_code_name1','use_code_name2','use_code_name3']` ?

Comment: @Maverick: You could simply combine the 3 columns into one (with str.join or any logic you'd like) and use this new column. Couldn't you?

Comment: Using this callback, I ran into xss issues and warnings in my browser. I posted an updated version that avoids this

Answer (score 0):

Surely enough, the answer came. Maybe this helps someone facing the same issue. If text is not getting mapped check that the df containing it is not a pandas series object and if so, convert to pandas df with the first line. The rest works.

```
df_text = df_old[['texts']]

xlat = guns2013['latitude'].tolist()
xlon = guns2013['longitude'].tolist()
locations = list(zip(xlat, xlon))
map2 = folium.Map(location=[38.9, -77.05], tiles='CartoDB dark_matter', 
zoom_start=1)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(map2)
try:
   for point in range(0, len(locations)):
   folium.Marker(locations[point], popup = folium.Popup(df_text['texts'] 
   [point])).add_to(marker_cluster)    
except:
   pass
map2
```

Comment: It's not a FastMarkerCluster, though, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the answer provided by @Filip Michalsky that avoids some xss/security issues I ran into using that solution.

```py
some_map = folium.Map(location=[df['latitude'].mean(), 
   df['longitude'].mean()], 
 zoom_start=9)
               
callback = ('function (row) {'
            'var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(row[0], row[1]), {color: "red"});'
            'var icon = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({'
            "icon: 'info-sign',"
            "iconColor: 'white',"
            "markerColor: 'green',"
            "prefix: 'glyphicon',"
            "extraClasses: 'fa-rotate-0'"
            '});'
            'marker.setIcon(icon);'
            "var popup = L.popup({maxWidth: '300'});"
            "const display_text = {text: row[2]};"
            "var mytext = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'display_text');"
            "mytext.textContent = display_text.text;"
            "popup.setContent(mytext);"
            "marker.bindPopup(popup);"
            'return marker};')
                             
some_map.add_child(FastMarkerCluster(df[['latitude', 'longitude','use_code_name']].values.tolist(), callback=callback))
```